# Вопрос про пространство имен в ООП

Tags: python, ооп, namespace

Есть класс:

```
class Person:
    name="Anna"
    info = {"Имя": name}
```

я изменяю атрибута класса name на "Billy"

`Person.name="Bully"`

но когда я обращаюсь к атрибуту info (словарь)

`print(Person.info)`,
то получаю:
{'Имя': 'Anna'}

Почему в словаре Anna, а не Billy? Ведь атрибут name="Billy"?
И как это исправить?

UPD:
Более того:

```
print(id(Person.name)) #id=4330356912
print(id(Person.info['Имя'])) #id=4330356784
```

Айдишники разные.
Почему они ссылаются на разные объекты??

Comment: А зачем вы одну переменную в два разных места в классе пытаетесь поместить? Python - вещь мощная и гибкая, но это обоюдоострое оружие. Переменных в нем вообще нет в классическом смысле этого слова.
Если просто, то id разные, потому, что это и есть разные объекты. При создании класса info удается инициировать, но далее вы уже работаете с разными объектами.
Чтобы ответить на "как исправить?" надо понимать, что вы хотите. Я бы убрал name="Anna" и оставил info = {"Имя":"Анна"}. Но я сам только изучаю Python пока. Так что не воспринимайте этот совет, как абсолютную истину.

Answer (score 1):

Данная проблема заключается скорее в том что у вас нет экземпляров класса, все атрибуты вашего класса являются статичными и должны меняться явно

Это можно обойти определив метод класса, который будет менять атрибуты класса
Например:

```py
class Person:
    name="Anna"
    info = {"Имя": name}

    def change_name(name):
      Person.name = name
      Person.info['Имя'] = name

Person.change_name("Bill")
print(Person.name) # "Bill"
print(Person.info) #  {"Имя": "Bill"}
```

Но я бы все же создал класс который будет иметь экземпляры

```py
class Person:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def get_info(self):
        return {"Имя": self.name}

obj = Person("Anna")
print(obj.name) # "Anna"
print(obj.get_info()) # {"Имя": "Anna"}

obj.name = "Bill"
print(obj.name) # "Bill"
print(obj.get_info()) #{"Имя": "Bill"}
```

Атрибут `self` указывает на конкретный экземпляр класса, в данном случае экземпляр мы его определили в переменную `obj`

Тем самым вы можете создавать несколько несвязанных между собой экземпляров одного класса

Comment: С экземплярами - да, отлично. А какой смысл в структуре первого примера? Зачем иметь и name="Anna" и  info = {"Имя": name}? Просто постарались не менять то, что в вопросе было?

Comment: да, максимально близко к приведенному примеру в вопросе, вдруг там есть какое  то важное обснование, почему должно быть именно две  таких переменных(что странно), а так да, можно было для первого примера просто метод из второго примера добавить и было бы то же самое

Comment: Полагаю, автор вопроса просто неудачно класс задал. Без конструктора стандартного, без возможности экземпляры иметь. А name = "Anna" - всё, что уцелело от конструктора.